# Redshift SQL WHERE statement doesn't seem to filter correctly?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

So I have a pretty simple query something like:

```
Select * from TableX where column1 = '2020-24'
```

However, in the results we get column 1 but it is not restricted to 2020-24 (week 24 in 2020), I see 2020-20 and 2020-05 etc.

I assume it's something to do with text/number formatting or something. I am using Redshift SQL, how can I fix this so it only shows rows where column 1 is '2020-24'? I tried use the WHERE with 2020-24 and with '2020-24' but both give the same result. I have heard I may need to cast with :: notation but not sure how..

Comment: What does `column1` contain?

Comment: Data of the form 'YYYY-WW'. Not sure what format it is saved as though..

Comment: You need to analyse it more to understand whats going on. Are all records returned or just some? use `select distinct column1` - any patterns?